# Can the scope of pytest fixtures be overridden?

Tags: python, scope, pytest, fixtures

Can the scope of pytest's built-in fixtures be changed?

This doesn't work:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def myFixture(tmpdir):
    pass
```

... because `tmpdir` is function-scoped:

```
ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'tmpdir' with a 'class' scoped request object, involved factories
```

Is it possible to override the scope of pytest's built-in fixtures, such that I could get a class-scoped `tmpdir` fixture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thats not possible,

the next release will include a session scoped fixture called tmpdir_factory

and an 'any' scope that will have the fixture once for each scope is planned as well

Comment: Any more recent follow up on this?  I am trying to access `capsys`, also a builtin, and I am having the same problem.  Right now I am just turning off the warning that appears, but I'd prefer to just be able to re-scope it.